# How to map a OpenSSL's cipher list to Java JSSE

Tags: tomcat, openssl, jetty, jsse

I've followed [Hardening your web servers ssl ciphers](https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/) guide which suggests using

```
ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5:!DSS
```

however i'm trying to configure a pure java ( Tomcat, Jetty ) based WebServer, not an Apache or OpenSSL based webserver. How to i figure out which JSSE cipher names corresponding to the result of

```
openssl ciphers -V 'ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5:!DSS'
```

Answer (score 13):

Java's JSSE cipher suite names correspond to the standard [TLS Cipher Suite List](http://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xml), where you can download a CSV file of the official codes and their names. The CSV file is called 'tls-parameters-4.csv'. With a little shell script you can map the OpenSSL name to the JSSE name - via the official hex code of the cipher.

```
$ cat openssl2jsse.sh 
#!/bin/bash
CODE=`openssl ciphers -V  | grep $1 | sed 's/ //g' | cut -d '-' -f1 `
grep $CODE tls-parameters-4.csv | cut -d ',' -f3

$ cat resolve.sh 
#!/bin/bash
COMBINEDLIST=
while read line
do
        ENTRY=`./openssl2jsse.sh $line`
        echo $ENTRY
        COMBINEDLIST=$COMBINEDLIST,$ENTRY
done
echo "ciphers="$COMBINEDLIST
```

piping the output of openssl ciphers -V into the resolve.sh script will result in a correctly sorted java cipher suite list.

```
$ openssl ciphers -V 'ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5:!DSS' | ./resolve.sh
... 
ciphers=,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
```

this script can save some minutes of manually mapping a list of values.

Answer (score 5):

OpenSSL online document contains a mapping of cipher suite names.
See [OpenSSL cipher suite names](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ciphers.html#CIPHER-SUITE-NAMES).

For example:

```
TLS v1.0 cipher suites.
TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5                   NULL-MD5
TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA                   NULL-SHA
TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5          EXP-RC4-MD5
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5                RC4-MD5
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA                RC4-SHA
TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC2_CBC_40_MD5      EXP-RC2-CBC-MD5
TLS_RSA_WITH_IDEA_CBC_SHA               IDEA-CBC-SHA
TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA       EXP-DES-CBC-SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA                DES-CBC-SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA           DES-CBC3-SHA
```

Comment: link is gone, this (third-party) site provides same info at time of wirting though. https://testssl.sh/openssl-rfc.mappping.html

Comment: For future readers, the referenced OpenSSL documentation can now be found [here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/ciphers.html#CIPHER-SUITE-NAMES).

Answer (score 0):

Get the IANA TLS Parameters file:

```
wget https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters-4.csv
```

Map OpenSSL cipher names to standard cipher names, preserving order:

```
openssl ciphers -V 'ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:ECDH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!MD5:!EXP:!RC4:!SEED:!DSS' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -i grep -F '{}' tls-parameters-4.csv | awk -F, '{print $3}'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to convert any OpenSSL (or GnuTLS, NSS, etc.) cipher name into IANA/standard/RFC cipher names by using [tls-map](https://github.com/sec-it/tls-map) library in ruby:

```rb
require 'tls_map'

tm = TLSmap::App.new

tm.search(:openssl, 'AES128-SHA', :iana) #=> {:iana=>"TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"}
```

It's also available as a CLI tool:

```
$ tls-map search openssl AES128-SHA -o iana
iana: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
```